Duplicate symbols only for boost json
I am working on a application that uses boost http and websocket clients. I need to parse the json response sent by the server and I am using boost/json for that. I have a HTTP client class and a websocket client class that get used in other classes, e.g classes A, B, C that get included into the main file. The compilation for each file is successful, but when linking everything together I get errors like:
The files are as follow:
HTTPClient.hpp
#ifndef HTTPCLIENT_HPP
#define HTTPCLIENT_HPP
#include <boost/json.hpp>

class HTTPClient.hpp {
    public:
        CBClient(boost::json json_val);
}
# endif

HTTPClient.cpp
#include <HTTPClient.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>

HTTPClient::CBClient(boost::json json_val) {
    // uses boost::ssl somewhere here
}

WebsocketClient.hpp
#ifndef WEBSOCKETCLIENT_HPP
#define WEBSOCKETCLIENT_HPP
#include <boost/json.hpp>

class WebsocketClient.hpp {
    public:
        CBClient(boost::json json_val);
}
# endif

WebsocketClient.cpp
#include <Websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <jwt-cpp/jwt.h>

WebsocketClient::CBClient(boost::json json_val) {
    // uses boost::ssl here
    // uses jwt here
}

A.hpp
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP
#include <Websocket.hpp>

class A.hpp {
    public:
        A();
        do_something();
    private:
        WebsocketClient ws;
}
# endif

B.hpp
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP
#include <HTTPClient.hpp>

class B.hpp {
    public:
        B();
        do_something_else();
    private:
        HTTPClient client;
}
# endif

Util.hpp
#ifndef UTIL_HPP
#define UTIL_HPP

// util functions
class Util {
    public:
        Util();
        foo();
}

# endif

Util.cpp
#include <Util.hpp>

Util::Util() {
    
}

Util::foo() {
    
}
# endif

main.cpp
#include <A.hpp
#include <B.hpp>
#include <Util.hpp>
int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    a.do_something();
    b.do_something_else();

    Util u;
    u.foo()
}

Makefile
CXX := g++

CXXFLAGS := -std=c++17 -O3 -Iinclude

INC_DIRS := -I/usr/local/include/boost_1_85_0/boost -I/usr/local/include/jwt-cpp 

LIB_DIRS := -L/opt/openssl@3/lib

LIBS := -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl

SRCS = main.cpp Util.cpp HTTPClient.cpp WebsocketClient.cpp A.cpp B.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

TARGET = main

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_DIRS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

.PHONY: clean

Error
duplicate symbol '__ZN5boost4json6detail16default_resource11do_allocateEmm' in:
    /app/src/A.o
    /app/src/main.o
    /app/src/B.o
    /app/src/C.o
    /app/src/HTTPClient.o
    /app/src/WebsocketClient.o

I have tried to add the include statements in the cpp file, but it's always 340 duplicate symbols. The weird part is that I also include other files from the boost library into the clients but they don't generate duplicate symbols. I want to know if there is something different for this library.

Please show a [mre]. I'm guessing following the instructions will fix your issue https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/overview.html#json.overview.requirements

duplicate symbols is nothing to do with header files - it is actually about the command you are using to compile.  Show us that and we can help.

@AlanBirtles I added the example, thanks for your help

@JerryJeremiah I added the makefile, thanks

All right, I am wrong.  You don't include any boost libraries at all so it must be something other than what I was imagining.

I did include boost::beast::ssl in both clients and I don't see any duplicate symbols for that library

Are you sure this is a [mre]? Does it actually reproduce your error? class HTTPClient.hpp doesn't look like valid c++

@JerryJeremiah I think I imagined the right bit accidentally :)

If you have trouble, see whether you accidentally copied this line from the jwt-cpp example:
 #include <boost/json/src.hpp> // You may require this if you are not building it elsewhere

You practically MUST have it somewhere because your Makefile failed to link -lboost_json anyways.
This will lead the implementation to be included in multiple translation units. That will explain your symptoms.
FIXED
I fixed your SSCCE: https://gist.github.com/sehe/61cd8d0198fe3645278e088f9d208955. All of the required minimal changes:
commit b86a75818143f9fb094508a615c8c365521c2d86 (HEAD -> main)
Author: sehe
Date:   Mon Oct 7 23:44:14 2024 +0200

    fixed

 A.hpp               | 8 ++++----
 B.hpp               | 8 ++++----
 HTTPClient.cpp      | 4 ++--
 HTTPClient.hpp      | 7 +++----
 Makefile            | 2 +-
 Util.cpp            | 5 ++---
 Util.hpp            | 4 ++--
 WebsocketClient.cpp | 6 +++---
 WebsocketClient.hpp | 6 +++---
 main.cpp            | 8 ++++----
 10 files changed, 28 insertions(+), 30 deletions(-)

It compiles fine. Full sample:

File A.cpp
#include "A.hpp"

A::A() : ws({}) {
    // uses boost::ssl here
    // uses jwt here
}

void A::do_something() {
    // uses boost::ssl here
    // uses jwt here
}


File A.hpp
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP
#include "WebsocketClient.hpp"

class A {
    public:
        A();
        void do_something();
    private:
        WebsocketClient ws;
};
# endif


File B.cpp
#include "B.hpp"

B::B() : client({}) {
}

void B::do_something_else() {}


File B.hpp
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP
#include "HTTPClient.hpp"

class B {
    public:
        B();
        void do_something_else();
    private:
        HTTPClient client;
};
# endif


File HTTPClient.cpp
#include "HTTPClient.hpp"
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>

HTTPClient::HTTPClient(boost::json::value json_val) {
    // uses boost::ssl somewhere here
}


File HTTPClient.hpp
#ifndef HTTPCLIENT_HPP
#define HTTPCLIENT_HPP
#include <boost/json.hpp>

class HTTPClient {
    public:
        HTTPClient(boost::json::value json_val);
};
# endif


File main.cpp
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include "Util.hpp"
int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    a.do_something();
    b.do_something_else();

    Util u;
    u.foo();
}


File Util.cpp
#include "Util.hpp"

Util::Util() {

}

void Util::foo() {

}


File Util.hpp
#ifndef UTIL_HPP
#define UTIL_HPP

// util functions
class Util {
    public:
        Util();
        void foo();
};

# endif


File WebsocketClient.cpp
#include "WebsocketClient.hpp"
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
//#include <jwt-cpp/jwt.h>

WebsocketClient::WebsocketClient(boost::json::value json_val) {
    // uses boost::ssl here
    // uses jwt here
}


File WebsocketClient.hpp
#ifndef WEBSOCKETCLIENT_HPP
#define WEBSOCKETCLIENT_HPP
#include <boost/json.hpp>

class WebsocketClient {
    public:
        WebsocketClient(boost::json::value json_val);
};
# endif


File Makefile
CXX := g++

CXXFLAGS := -std=c++17 -O3 -Iinclude

INC_DIRS := -I/usr/local/include/boost_1_85_0/boost -I/usr/local/include/jwt-cpp 

LIB_DIRS := -L/opt/openssl@3/lib

LIBS := -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl -lboost_json

SRCS = main.cpp Util.cpp HTTPClient.cpp WebsocketClient.cpp A.cpp B.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

TARGET = main

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_DIRS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
 rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

.PHONY: clean



